# Differentiate between different devices

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, mobile, tablet

How do we differentiate between the following devices in ASP.NET (C#)?

- Mobile
- Desktop PC
- Tablet
- E-Reader

I am pretty new to *making* mobile websites, but I have always made sure existing sites work great on mobile devices. The problem I face now is that I actually need to make different versions for all these devices, and I have not been able to do much research on this as there appears to be not much information that I can find regarding this issue.

The only things that popup are things like Mobile website generators etc. Definitely not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Why on earth would one make _different_ versions _per device_? That's insanely inconsistent. Make one, and make it adaptable (_responsive_ (?))

Comment: I'm not able to say why, but different versions is the main point of this project. It's a requirement that I need to abide by and it's proving very difficult to find the right information.

Comment: i think only difference for display size .

Answer (score 0):

You must look at responsive design templates, it is suggested by many because it is always hard to adapt the website according to each device.